# unable to upgrade old react native project with API level 28 to API level 31

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

I have a 2 year old react native project created based on version 61.5 having API level version 28. Now I am trying to upgrade it. I have upgraded the gradle version to latest, react native is also upgraded, solved the issues that came in. My target version change are as follow

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        supportLibVersion = "31.0.0"
```

when I run react-native run-android app builds successfully, installs it in emulator, but I am getting the error as shown in the screenshot, because it doesn't suggest where the error is to be able to figure out the root cause. And if I run "yarn start" the app loads and works properly.
Does anyone have experienced this kind of issue? Can any one please suggest how to get more insight into the error message to find which file is causing it.

Comment: Upgrading a outdated react native project is not easy, please go through with the [Upgrade Helper][1]. Good luck to you.


  [1]: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/